# Saving everyone's profile page while saving infos in database HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin, profile

I have a different register way. Firstly,  you need to register from a game which, saves your username and password in database.

I made a login system, where you can log in with in-game username and password to see different informations about your account.

Currently, no profile is being saved. It saves only in database, where, with username and account you can log in and see your own details.

But as an admin, I want to check another player account's and to see their details, but I can't because it won't save psychally in user documents and I don't have acces to their passwords to log in.

How can I achieve to save in a user folder,  every username.php  files, identicaly used in profile.php model ?

I want to do a html page, with a search form where i'll just type username, and click "search"  and new page shall appear with url www.domain.com/users/username.

how? Can it be done without URL rewriting? (specially that i'm working on localhost now, later i'll do it via uploading on a host)

my problem is that, every user can see only their own profile, using profile.php I have only profle.php which extracts from database informations of login user.  It doesn't matter if you're admin or not because you can see only your profile.

part PHP of profile.php

```
 <?php 
include("config.php"); //including our config.php 
session_start(); //starting session 
error_reporting(0); 

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) //if session is set, so if user is logged in... 
{ 
    $username = $_SESSION['username']; //setting variable username as one from session 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");  //selecting all from table users where username is name that your is loged in 
    //echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']; //saying welcome to user!  
    //echo "<h5 class='title-small center'>Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."</h5>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //looping thousgt table to get informations 
{
        $Username = $row['Username']; //selecting user name, change 'username' to your field name  
        $Headshots = $row['Headshots']; //selecting user money, change 'money' to your field name  
        $BanditsKilled = $row['BanditsKilled']; //selecting user score, change 'score' to your field name  
        $Murders = $row['Murders']; //selecting user kills, change 'kills' to your field name  
        $Backpack1 = $row['Backpack']; 
        if($Backpack1 == 0) {
            $Backpack = "Rucsac&nbsp;simplu";
        } else if($Backpack1 == 1) {
            $Backpack = "Rucsac&nbsp;din&nbsp;panza";
        } else if($Backpack1 == 2) {
            $Backpack = "Rucsac&nbsp;mic&nbsp;de&nbsp;armata";
        } else if($Backpack1 == 3) {
            $Backpack = "Rucsac&nbsp;de&nbsp;armata";
        } else if($Backpack1 == 4) {
            $Backpack = "Rucsac&nbsp;VIP";
        }





        $skin = $row['pSkin'];
        $BackpackSlotsUsed = $row['BackpackSlotsUsed'];
        $BackpackSlots = $row['BackpackSlots'];
        $pHour = $row['pHour'];
        $pWeap1 = $row['pWeap1'];
        $pWeap1 = $row['pWeap1'];
        $pWeap2 = $row['pWeap2'];
        $pWeap3 = $row['pWeap3'];
        $pWeap4 = $row['pWeap4'];
        $pWeap5 = $row['pWeap5'];
        $pWeap6 = $row['pWeap6'];
        $IP = $row['IP'];
        $pAmmo1 = $row['pAmmo1'];
        $pAmmo2 = $row['pAmmo2'];
        $pAmmo3 = $row['pAmmo3'];
        $pAmmo4 = $row['pAmmo4'];
        $pAmmo5 = $row['pAmmo5'];
        $pAmmo6 = $row['pAmmo6'];
        $pJailed = $row['pJailed'];
        $pVIP1 = $row['pVIP'];
        if($pVIP1 == 0) {
            $pVIP = "Fara&nbsp;VIP";
        } else if($pVIP1 == 1) {
            $pVIP = "VIP&nbsp;Bronze";
        } else if($pVIP1 == 2) {
            $pVIP = "VIP&nbsp;Silver";
        } else if($pVIP1 == 3) {
            $pVIP = "VIP&nbsp;Gold";
        } else if($pVIP1 == 4) {
            $pVIP = "VIP&nbsp;Platinum";
        }

        $pHour = $row['pHour'];
        $Blood = $row['pBlood'];
        $pThrist = $row['pThrist'];
        $pHunger = $row['pHunger'];
        $pAliveTime = $row['pAliveTime'];
        $pAdminLevel1 = $row['pAdminLevel'];
                if($pAdminLevel1 == 0) {
            $pAdminLevel = "Fara&nbsp;Admin";
        } else if($pAdminLevel1 == 1) {
            $pAdminLevel = "Trial&nbsp;Moderator";
        } else if($pAdminLevel1 == 2) {
            $pAdminLevel = "Moderator&nbsp;Team";
        } else if($pAdminLevel1 == 3) {
            $pAdminLevel = "Administrator&nbsp;Team";
        } else if($pAdminLevel1 == 4) {
            $pAdminLevel = "Support&nbsp;Team";
        } else if($pAdminLevel1 == 5) {
            $pAdminLevel = "Management&nbsp;Team";
        } else if($pAdminLevel1 == 6) {
            $pAdminLevel = "Developer&nbsp;Team";
        } else if($pAdminLevel1 == 7) {
            $pAdminLevel = "Community&nbsp;Owner";

        }



        $Helper1 = $row['Helper'];
                if($Helper1 == 0) {
            $Helper = "Fara&nbsp;Helper";
        } else if($Helper1 == 1) {
            $Helper = "Esti&nbsp;Helper";
        }

$weapons = array(
    'Fara&nbsp;arma',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'Bata&nbsp;de&nbsp;Baseball',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'Katana',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'Pistol',
    'Silenced Pistol',
    '',
    'Shotgun',
    '',
    'Spaz Shotgun',
    '',
    'MP5',
    'AK-47',
    'M4A1',
     '',
     '',
     'Country Rifle',
     'Sniper Rifle',
     '',
     '',
     '',
     '',
     '',
     '',
     '',
     '',
     '',
     'Night&nbsp;Vision&nbsp;Goggles',
     'Thermal&nbsp;Vision&nbsp;Goggles' 
);  

    }  ?>

    <div class="test">
      <h1 id="title-1">Bun venit,<em><span></span><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></em>Detalii cont:</h1>
     <center> <a href="logout.php"> <font color="white">Log out.</font> </a></center>
```

I want to make a "Users" document, where somehow every user profile shall be automaticaly entered when users register, giving me acces to "domain.com/users/profile" and with the model of profile.php, but with their information.

Comment: You have given no code to work with, we can't help you until we see the issue in your code. Admin functionality shouldn't need user password to see their information, that is a horrible design flaw.

Comment: @MinistryofChaps  I can see their informations only via database, but I want to see it via my user control panel.  But i have only profile.php , which shows only login user's informations, as an admin I see only mine, not other users. I don't know how to make URL to every user to see their infos.

Comment: @MinistryofChaps just updated with code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a roles or privileges system. So, for simplicity, you have the following roles

```
administrator
player
```

Then, you can create an `admin` account with `administrator` privileges. This account is created by you, and only used by you. This account will give you access to the special admin section, and there, you can create pages to view accounts of all users. Also you may have special operations, such as terminating accounts, resetting passwords, managing credit ...etc.

And when a new player registers his or her account, he/she would have a `player` privilege assigned to him/her. This account will give access to only his/her profile.

If you need someone else to be an admin, you can create a new admin account, `admin2` for example, and assign `administrator` role to that account.

Maybe you want to have more layers for roles. Such as

```
administrator
manager
player
```

Where `administrator` is only for you, to allow you create/delete other admins, and `manager` can do everything the `admin` does except he/she cannot add or delete administrators or managers. This way, you prevent someone from locking you out of the system on purpose if he/she decides to take over your business.

You have to plan according to your needs though. The above is just an example.

Comment: I have "pAdminLevel" in my database,which will determinate if an user can or no see another profiles.   But my problem is that, every user can see only their own profile.

Comment: I am not sure what that means really. But I think the idea I gave you is just to give you direction. It is up to you how to implement. The point is, you have to create roles/privileges and assign those roles to different users.

Comment: my problem is that, every user can see only their own profile, using profile.php    I have only profle.php which extracts from database informations of login user.

Comment: You have to make your `profile.php` detect the role of the user that is logging in, and if the role is `administrator` then display different interface than if the role is `player`

Comment: OK, what am I supposed to do? I told you what you have to do. The change you have to make affects the database (table for roles/privileges), and a one-to-many relationship to your users table. Then you have to update your `profile.php` to deal with roles. I do not think I can help here, because you are now talking about design issues that go far beyond the scope of this question.